# I am trying to make the insertion point default to the first text box after a button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a winforms app that has 6 buttons that after pressed they create or remove text boxes as needed IE: Name, date, age, etc.

Each of the buttons are different questions but how do i make it when i press the button it automatically puts the insertion point(type indicator) in the first text box.

here is my button1_Click method

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Visible = false;
        label3.Visible = false;
        textBox2.Visible = false;
        textBox3.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = true;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        button7.Visible = true;
        choice = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for `textBox1.Focus()`?

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
textBox1.Focus();
```